# Grab the latest tag name from a docker image via CLI?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to parse out the latest tag name from the docker cli after filtering a particular repository:

```
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
reponame   28f320b6            c22a7d6d08d3        24 hours ago        159MB
reponame   v1                  597cbaf5aeb1        46 hours ago        159MB
```

which is a result of `docker images reponame`

I want to grab just the hash of the latest tag, in this case `28f320b6`. How can I go about this?

Comment: Latest or first tag oO ?

Comment: No accepted answer? ^^ Anything wrong with mine?

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
docker images reponame | awk 'NR>1 && $1=="reponame" {print $2;exit}'
```